# Как отсортировать HashMap<String, String> по ключу по последовательности из другого списка

Tags: java, сортировка, map, java-hashmap, hashmap

Есть Map<String, String>

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "1000");
map.put("B", "1001");
map.put("C", "1002");
map.put("D", "1003");
map.put("E", "1004");
```

Есть список

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("B", "E", "A", "C");
```

Мне нужно что бы элементы из map выводились в последовательности из list.
Если элемента с каким ключом нет в map то пропустить, взять следующий, а если ключа нет в списке то вывести в конце

Comment: Итерируемся по листу и делаем map.get(list.get(i)); Если `null`, пропускаем, берем следующий

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я сделал немного по другому. LinkedHashMap в цикле добавлял

Comment: То вам нужен был итератор в нужном порядке? Так бы и сказали...